# htaccess to ignore specific part of the URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to change language of a website to english when URL has /en/ after the domain. PHP changes a translation file when url has that /en/ after the domain.

My system adds that /en/ part to all links, even CSS-file's URL etc. It works ok, but I cannot reach any files when that part is in the URL. I still want to find all the files and folders even when the /en/ part is there.

For example:

http://domain.com/en/images/image.png

shows the image from here

http://domain.com/images/image.png

But it has to keep the /en/ part in the URL, so the language won't change.

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This redirects the URL, but it removes the /en/ part. :/

```
RedirectMatch ^/en/(.*) /$1
```

So is it even possible to redirect and leave the original url? If not, is it possible to redirect (and change URL) only when it is existing folder or a file? Thanks. :)

Comment: Lookup: "Internal rewrite mod_rewrite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `RedirectMatch` line with this:

```
RewriteRule ^en/([^.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked when I put it after Options +FollowSymlinks. :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.